# Superscript/subscript in Joomla Article Title

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is there a way to add superscript or subscript in Joomla Article Title words?
as Joomla cleans the tags from title area.

Thanks

Comment: Is it only needed for a couple of articles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We resolved this problem for a client once by adding something like `***` to the title, for example, if the title is "This is the 2nd article", then we will have in the title something like "This is the `2/***nd***/` article", and then, in the template displaying the article, we replace instances of `/***` (in the title) to `<sup>` and instances of `***/` to `</sup>`.

Comment: Did you use Regular Labs ReReplacer or similar?

Comment: @NeilRobertson No - we resolved by using a simple `str_replace` at the template level.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to place the title as a H1 into the content and not render the Joomla title in the template